# Dataframe pandas plot chart per row

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have a large Pandas dataframe with a lot of columns and I need to plot a chart per row.

For now I have this in my code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

[...]

df = pd.DataFrame() # DataFrame with 13 columns

for index,row in df.iterrows():
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(row)
    plt.set_title(row)
    plt.bar(df2)
    plt.savefig('./plots/chart_' + index)
```

But the df2 dataframe inside the for loop is empty...

Comment: You don't need a loop. There is a cleaner way to do it. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need df2 for other operations? If not you can skip that step and create your chart directly by using the row variable by changing your code to:

```
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    plt.bar(row.keys(),row.values)
    plt.savefig('./plots/chart_' + index)
```

Answer (score 0):

An efficient and clean way to plot pandas df per row is to transpose it.

Suppose we happened to have a small `df` with 13 columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,13))
df.shape
(10, 13)
```

Plot per column:

```
df.plot.bar()
plt.legend(df.columns, loc="right");
```

[image]

Plot per row:

```
df.T.plot.bar()
plt.legend(df.columns, loc="right");
```

[image]